# Write a script to copy data from a text file to Excel file

Tags: copy

I need to automate the process of copying data from a text file to an excel file. The text file is not a delimited file and the import function in excel would not work. It is generated by a quantum mechanical calculation. The following shows a snippet from the text file. Normally, after inspecting the text file and deciding on the number of state of interest (for example in this file it is state 27). I would copy the value of 'Energy" paste it into Excel cell, then copy the X component of state dipole and paste into Excel cell, etc. (7 copy-paste in total)

Since I have around 500 text files, it will be good to have a script where after I specify the state of interest, the script will copy the data and paste it into Excel. I am not sure what scripting language would be the easiest to accomplish that. Thanks in advance!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------



27 (  1)->( 27)    Energy         52022.4  cm-1,  (192.2 nm)
        State Dipole      51.3067  

        Oscillator Strength
          length          0.0000

                State Dipole     44.3032   -13.5901  -22.0208

        Transition Dipole
          Electric (length)  -0.0333    -0.0049    0.0301


        Occ. MO   -> Unocc. MO
        **********************

        (  65)    ->  (  70)       0.053470
        (  69)    ->  (  70)       0.985098
        (  69)    ->  (  72)       0.127470
```

---

```
28 (  1)->( 28)    Energy         52220.3  cm-1,  (191.5 nm)
        State Dipole      13.7414  

        Oscillator Strength
          length          0.0356

                State Dipole     10.2756     9.0835   -0.8526

        Transition Dipole
          Electric (length)  -0.6146    -0.5058   -0.9047


        Occ. MO   -> Unocc. MO
        **********************

        (  58)    ->  (  75)       0.087104
        (  59)    ->  (  71)      -0.085481
        (  59)    ->  (  75)      -0.123631
        (  60)    ->  (  75)      -0.208451
        (  61)    ->  (  71)      -0.056656
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're up for learning a programming language, I would suggest learning a bit of perl to parse the file.  Perl is great for ad hoc parsing tasks.

There's an excellent perl module, `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` that can generate your spreadsheet, also.  You can read about it on CPAN:  [http://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel)